# AJAX Post request answer didn't arrive but shown in network

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, http, post

I wrote a code which sends a POST (jquery AJAX) request for login and then it needs the answer to continue the process.
I sent the answer from the server (exactly like get requests answers which work).
The response content it shown in network dev tools but AJAX is like nothing arrived.
I think it thinks that there is no content.
This is the server answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:  application/json
Content-Length: 67
Date: Tue, 12 May 2020 00:46:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

['{"username": "ooo0", "time": "8:30PM", "txt": 890, "value": 90}']
```

This is the AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send?",
        data: json_data,
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg); 
            alert(msg);
            }
        })
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the server language you use? I was have same issue when I use PHP, it was happened because there is a white space before the opening of the <?php script

Comment: Not PHP, Jquery and Java Script

Comment: I now checked and it seems that the right information arrived as error in xhr.response. 
I don’t know why it happened... The code is 200 OK, and network said that the response is ok.